# Configuring Application Load Balancer and JNLP port

Tags: devops, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I have deployed my jenkins server in ECS fargate cluster and configured it with Application Load balancer through HTTP protocol. i need to create a ecs agent to do tasks in ECS cluster. while creating the tunnel connection through for jenkins master only the ip address created by the ecs task works fine (eg task ip:50000) but when i give my ALB DNS:50000 the agent becomes offline. if anyone knows the solution kindly help me ????

i tried adding jnlp port with my ALB but it doesn't work. does anyone know how to configure my ALB ( Application load balancer) to listen to jnlp port 50000?